# how to remove part of a link?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have this link:
"sound:[https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ArSrNa/CDN/audio/%E6%B5%85%E5%A0%B4%E4%BD%B3%E8%8B%97%20-%20love%20the%20way.mp3?"](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ArSrNa/CDN/audio/%E6%B5%85%E5%A0%B4%E4%BD%B3%E8%8B%97%20-%20love%20the%20way.mp3?%22)

I would like to remove this from the beginning of the link: "sound:",  and this from the end "?" so that I can play the audio on the link.

this is what i have so far. Every help is welcome.

```html
<audio id="myAudio">
<source src="sound:https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ArSrNa/CDN/audio/%E6%B5%85%E5%A0%B4%E4%BD%B3%E8%8B%97%20-%20love%20the%20way.mp3?" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>



<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button> 

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

s = x.replace('[sound:','').replace(']','');


function playAudio() { 
  s.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
  s.pause(); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Is this what you are trying to acheive? `"sound:https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ArSrNa/CDN/audio/%E6%B5%85%E5%A0%B4%E4%BD%B3%E8%8B%97%20-%20love%20the%20way.mp3?".split(/sound\:|\?/)[1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
<source src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ArSrNa/CDN/audio/%E6%B5%85%E5%A0%B4%E4%BD%B3%E8%8B%97%20-%20love%20the%20way.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

This would achieve exactly what you wanted. Why need a script?

Comment: actually this is the file "[sound:naver-7e496e36-c75980ec-07a42358-77d6e150-ee2df018.mp3]". I need to remove this "[sound:" and this "]". because I have thousands of files like this and to play them I need a practical script.

Comment: @ivanmartins please add this to your question, it's really a vital piece of information. Otherwise people might misunderstand and start downvoting your post.

Answer (score 0):

There will almost certainly be a more robust regex based answer to this but the simplest way in my eyes, if you can rely on the end of the string always ending in `.mp3` is to do string replacement. So it seems you pretty much have it with a couple of minor mistakes.

This `s = x.replace('[sound:','').replace(']','');` should be `s = x.replace('sound:','').replace('.mp3?','.mp3');`

Adding `.mp3` to the replacement will ensure no other question marks are removed out of context

Comment: I'm going to place the URL regExp here since you mention it: `myString.match(/https?\:\/\/[^\?\]]+/)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you are trying to do:

```
myURLstring.split(/sound\:|\?|\]/)[1]
```

```js
var string1 = 'sound:https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ArSrNa/CDN/audio/%E6%B5%85%E5%A0%B4%E4%BD%B3%E8%8B%97%20-%20love%20the%20way.mp3?'
var string2 = '[sound:https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ArSrNa/CDN/audio/%E6%B5%85%E5%A0%B4%E4%BD%B3%E8%8B%97%20-%20love%20the%20way.mp3]'
console.log(string1.split(/sound\:|\?|\]/)[1]);
console.log(string2.split(/sound\:|\?|\]/)[1]);
```